How to remove tzname string from tzinfo?
In Python, I want to remove the string of timezone name in tzinfo:
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo

Where x is:
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400), 'CDT')

How can I turn it into
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400))

Thank you so much!

each python object/variable is a class. And if class have a property 'timezone' you can't remove it by default. However this also doesn't mean that you need to use all class attributes when using the variable. However from what I understand you'd like to convert tzinfo class to timedelta class. I guess you can do this following way:
import datetime 

time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
x = time.astimezone().tzinfo.utcoffset(None)


It works! I got what I want by using this timedelta x and datetime.timezone(x) - Thank you!

If you want the fixed offset of the default time zone, use .utcoffset() directly on the aware datetime and create a new timezone without a name:
import datetime as dt

x = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc).astimezone()
print(repr(x.tzinfo))
print(repr(dt.timezone(x.utcoffset())))

Output:
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200), 'Pacific Daylight Time')
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200))

